# NGINX file not found for php files

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, nginx

I have the following setup.

Nginx as a web server. Passing request to unicorn which runs as my ruby on rails server. I now want to install wordpress at mysite.com/blog. I therefore have installed and configured php and fastcgi. The nginx config is as follows:

```
upstream unicorn_mysite {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mysite.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name mysite.com;
 return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /opt/certs/thinbundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/certs/mysite.key;
  server_name mysite.com;

  root /opt/www/mysite/current/public;

  location /blog {
           index index.php;

           if (!-e $request_filename) {
           rewrite  ^(.*)$  /blog/index.php?q=$1  last;
                                      }

                location ~ .php(?|$) {
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/www/mysite_wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                }
  }


  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;  
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_mysite;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header Front-End-Htps on;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

and the fastcgi_params file in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params contains:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

When I go to mysite.com/blog I get this :

[image]

When I look at the nginx logs I see:

```
2016/03/15 11:26:35 [error] 23109#23109: *29 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.14.209.183, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /blog HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.mysite.com"
2016/03/15 11:28:36 [error] 23109#23109: *35 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.14.209.183, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /blog HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.mysite.com"
2016/03/15 11:32:12 [error] 23109#23109: *38 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.14.209.183, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /blog HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.mysite.com"
2016/03/15 11:36:41 [error] 23109#23109: *45 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.14.209.183, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /blog HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.mysite.com"
```

Can somebody please help me fix this File not found. Which file is not found? and where is it looking for it - i.e why can't it find it! None of these errors help me identify the cause of the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was because of this :

http://web.archive.org/web/20141105045103/http://www.linux-support.com/cms-xxx/ubuntu-developers-thomas-ward-nginx-changes-in-debian-causing-default-config-fastcgi-users-issues

basically in my nginx config file I was pointing to /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params instead of the correct file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf. Both of these files existed in my nginx install - so this was not easy to find or workout that we should be using fastcgi.conf.